# In Visual Studio, how do I override a project property value which is not inherited without editing the vcxproj file

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

In Visual Studio 2013/VC++ for a statically linked executable, how do I override a property setting, when it is in bold( not inherited) by using a property sheet? I cannot edit the vcxproj file as it is auto generated and direct edits are lost when it is generated.

Details:

I have a Visual studio solution that contains two projects:

1. Dependency.vcxproj --> Generates Dependency.lib which is a static library.
2. MyProg.vcxproj --> Links to Dependency.lib and generates MyProg.exe

Of these, Dependency.vcxproj is auto generated and I do not have control over its generation( It is generated from a build script every time I run it). I see that It has *Optimization* set to **O2** and also has *Debug Information Format* set to **none**. ( Both of these are in bold - so I assume they have been explicitly turned off). However, to allow for debug, I want to override these properties and set *Optimization* **Disabled** and *Debug Information Format* to **/Zi** when I am building it as part of my solution.

I tried overriding it using a .props file for the project, but the values are not overridden - I read somewhere that a property needs to inherit for a props sheet to override.

Is there any way to override such an already modified property without editing the vcxproj file itself?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you lib project is actually using your .props file. Means, it has to be included in the project. If you want to override already defined property with .props, this .props needs to be included after the property is set to override it. Basically .props work similar to text inclusion.

Another option could be to use .user file to override the properties (.user may be already included into generated .vcxproj, with condition "if exists"). But anyways you need to find a way to include your file re-defining the linker properties into the .vcxproj file.

Normally, you use "debug" vs "release" configurations to allow/disallow debugging. Maybe you just need to select "debug" configuration for your solution (this one can be found in the toolbar, a combo box in Visual studio) and then build?

If this is not the case, I would say the easiest way out may be modifying the script you use to generate the project to generate the project you want.

Comment: Yep, modify the script to not produce override settings in the vcxproj, and to include a .props file, and never have this problem again.